# SIGABRT when calling [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed]

Tags: ios, sigabrt, magicalrecord

I'm new to "Magical Record" and pretty new to iOS programming in general. I'm just trying to get things set up. I've followed the instructions in http://yannickloriot.com/2012/03/magicalrecord-how-to-make-programming-with-core-data-pleasant/, but instead of:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [MagicalRecordHelpers setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];
    // ...
    return YES;
}
```

I think I'm using a newer version which changes the AppDelegate to:

```
@implementation LSAppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application{
    [MagicalRecord cleanUp];
}
@end
```

When running, I get a SIGABRT at:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectModel *) MR_mergedObjectModelFromMainBundle;
{
    return [self mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
}
```

The stack trace looks like:

```
#0  0x00011f7e in +[NSManagedObjectModel(MagicalRecord) MR_mergedObjectModelFromMainBundle] at /Developer/projects/demo/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObjectModel+MagicalRecord.m:33
#1  0x00011eb4 in +[NSManagedObjectModel(MagicalRecord) MR_defaultManagedObjectModel] ()
#2  0x000147ca in +[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(MagicalRecord) MR_coordinatorWithSqliteStoreNamed:withOptions:] ()
#3  0x000148fa in +[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(MagicalRecord) MR_coordinatorWithSqliteStoreNamed:] ()
#4  0x00016546 in +[MagicalRecord(Setup) setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:] ()
#5  0x000026eb in -[LSAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] ()
```

I have no idea what I did wrong or what I can do to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Try putting the `setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:` line inside a @try/@catch and logging the exception description in the @catch part.  If might give better error information.

Comment: Of course!! Thank you so much for the suggestion. The problem was the "can't merge models with two different entities named ...". Not sure why, though. I had started over on my project a couple of times and had made a backup copy of the code. It appears the backup copies of the entity objects were being included for some reason. Once I deleted the copy, it now appears to be working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you were having issues with Core Data migration.  Un-installing the app from the simulator will force a fresh SQLite database, which is handy while you're changing up the schema during development.

Later, you might want to switch to `-setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed`, which handles trivial migrations, as long as you create new version of the managed object model.  See [Model File Format and Versions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmModelFormat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH3-SW1) for info on how to create those versions.

Comment: Hi Otto, I am running an exception when trying to iniitalize the MOC using MR, can you help me out? here is my post, thanx. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918169/assertion-failure-in-nsmanagedobjectcontext-mr-defaultcontext-when-trying